# GLSL Simple example shows blanks screen on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a simple program to work. I am using SD2 + OpenGL Shading Language. Also, I'm trying to this on MacOS, more precisely 10.15.5.
I know Apple is deprecating OpenGL in favor of Metal, but it seems they are still supporting at least up to OpenGL 4.1.

This is a simplified version of the program I'm trying to run:

```cpp
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

const int WIDTH = 600;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

const int numVAOs = 1;

GLuint renderingProgram;
GLuint vao[numVAOs];

GLuint createShaderProgram() {
    GLint vertCompiled;
    GLint fragCompiled;
    GLint linked;

    const char *vshaderSource =
            "#version 410\n"
            "void main(void)\n"
            "{gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); }";
    const char *fshaderSource =
            "#version 410\n"
            "out vec4 color; \n"
            "void main(void)\n"
            "{color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);}";

    GLuint vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vshaderSource, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fshaderSource, NULL);

    glCompileShader(vShader);
    glCompileShader(fShader);

    GLuint vfProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, vShader);
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(vfProgram);

    return vfProgram;
}

int main() {
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_GLContext gl_context;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "OpenGL Shaders",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            WIDTH,
            HEIGHT,
            SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    gl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    renderingProgram = createShaderProgram();
    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(numVAOs, vao);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(vao[0]);

    bool isRunning = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (isRunning) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    isRunning = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(renderingProgram);
        glPointSize(30.0f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gl_context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

This shows only a blank screen and on the console it prints **4.1 ATI-3.9.15**. So I am sure I got the correct profile.

I have tried playing with the headers. It seems i don't need a library to get extension names, seems Apple already has them int heir OpenGL headers.

The full program has some routines which handles errors when creating/linking the shaders and I can tell they are not failing to compile/link.

The program should show a point in the middle of the screen, but is not showing anything but a white screen(the clear color).

Any idea what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use the APPLE extension for VAOs and not the core version? Do you get any error when calling `glGetError()`?

Comment: No reason. That is what I found available. glGetError is not getting any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I made it work.

The problem was this lines:

```cpp
glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(numVAOs, vao);
glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(vao[0]);
```

For some reason, the APPLE version of those doesn't work.
What I did is:

- Install GLEW with brew (which I thought I didn't need)
- Update my cmake file to link glew correctly
- Add glew headers and `glew_init()`
- Replace the APPLE functions with "normal" ones.

```
glGenVertexArrays(numVAOs, vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
```

Now the program shows points/triangles

Hope this helps anyone else in the future.